# Java 8: multiple AveragingDouble() in single Stream API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Product> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(new Product("abc", 123, 4455));
        list1.add(new Product("bbc", 5454, 4467755));
        list1.add(new Product("abc", 66, 446555));
        list1.add(new Product("cc", 12773, 4455));
        list1.add(new Product("abc", 13323, 445875));
        list1.add(new Product("abddc", 12335, 445755));

        Map<String, List<Product>> result = list1.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getAstcls));

        result.forEach((astcls, products) -> {
            double averageUnits = products.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getUnits));

            double averageMktVal = products.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getMktVal));

            System.out.println("astcls: " + astcls);
            System.out.println("Average Units: " + averageUnits);
            System.out.println("Average MktVal: " + averageMktVal);
            System.out.println("-----");
        });
    }
}
public class Product {

    private String astcls;
    private double units;
    private double mktVal;

    public Product() {
        super();
    }

    public double getMktVal() {
        return mktVal;
    }

    public void setMktVal(double mktVal) {
        this.mktVal = mktVal;
    }

    public double getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    public void setUnits(double units) {
        this.units = units;
    }

    public String getAstcls() {
        return astcls;
    }

    public void setAstcls(String astcls) {
        this.astcls = astcls;
    }

    public Product(String astcls, double units, double mktVal) {
        super();
        this.astcls = astcls;
        this.units = units;
        this.mktVal = mktVal;
    }

}
```

I have list of Product object as shown above :

Now I need to find the average of each fields group by astcls.

like : group by astcls("abc") and sum of this group units,sum of this group mktval and so on..

i don't know how can i use Collectors.averagingDouble() for multiple fields in single Stream API(JAVA 8) and retrive Map<String,List<Product>>.

Comment: get a list of all the astcls, then for each value, perform a stream()-filter() and use the results to get the results

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Currently I have to create a new stream for each field.

Answer (score 2):

For this case you can use the Teeing Operator:

```
result.forEach((astcls, products) -> {
        Result r = products.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                        Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getUnits),
                        Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getMktVal),
                        (avgUnits, avgMktVal) -> new Result(astcls, avgUnits, avgMktVal)
                ));

        System.out.println("astcls: " + astcls);
        System.out.println("Average Units: " + r.getAvgUnits());
        System.out.println("Average MktVal: " + r.getAvgMktVal());
        System.out.println("-----");
    });
```

It basically splits one Stream into two. The only downside is that you have to create a separate Result-Class:

```
class Result {

    private String astcls;
    private double avgUnits;
    private double avgMktVal;

    //constructor, getter, setter left out
}
```

Sadly if you want to do it over more than two fields / operations it get's a bit more ugly:

```
Result r = products.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.teeing(Collectors.teeing(
                                Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getUnits),
                                Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getMktVal),
                                (avgUnits, avgMktVal) -> new Result(astcls, avgUnits, avgMktVal)
                        ),
                        Collectors.summingDouble(Product::getMktVal),
                        (r2, sumMktVal) -> {
                            r2.setSumMktVal(sumMktVal);
                            return r2;
                        }
                ));
```

Basically you have to use the Teeing operator multiple times.

However if you only interested in those two fields, but multiple operations you can also use the summarizingDouble-Collector:

```
    Result r = products.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                        Collectors.summarizingDouble(Product::getUnits),
                        Collectors.summarizingDouble(Product::getMktVal),
                        (summarizingUnits, summarizingMktVal) -> new Result(astcls, summarizingUnits, summarizingMktVal)
                ));
```

And by changing up the Result class like this:

```
class Result {

    private String astcls;
    private DoubleSummaryStatistics sumStatsUnits;
    private DoubleSummaryStatistics sumStatsMktVal;
}
```

The DoubleSummaryStatistics has getters for the count, sum, min, max and the average which is pretty much all the operations I can think of. Keeps it nice and clean.

Edit:

If you want to be super clean (or because you don't have access to java 13 and teeing) it's possible to write your own TeeingCollector:

```
public static <T, A, RT, R> Collector<T, ?, R> teeingList(List<Collector<T, A, RT>> downstreams, Function<List<RT>, R> merger) {
        Stream<Supplier<A>> supplier = downstreams.stream().map(Collector::supplier);
        List<BiConsumer<A, T>> accumulator = downstreams.stream().map(Collector::accumulator).toList();
        List<BinaryOperator<A>> combiner = downstreams.stream().map(Collector::combiner).toList();
        List<Function<A, RT>> finisher = downstreams.stream().map(Collector::finisher).toList();

        class ListBox {
            final List<A> as = supplier.map(Supplier::get).toList();

            void add(T t) {
                for (int i = 0; i < accumulator.size(); i++) {
                    accumulator.get(i).accept(as.get(i), t);
                }
            }

            ListBox combine(ListBox other) {
                for (int i = 0; i < accumulator.size(); i++) {
                    combiner.get(i).apply(as.get(i), other.as.get(i));
                }
                return this;
            }

            R get() {
                List<RT> rts = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < accumulator.size(); i++) {
                    rts.add(finisher.get(i).apply(as.get(i)));
                }

                return merger.apply(rts);
            }
        }

        return Collector.of(
                ListBox::new,
                ListBox::add,
                ListBox::combine,
                ListBox::get
        );
    }
```

This is basically the same code the Teeing Operator uses except that I am using Lists and not two separate fields.

This makes it super clean to use:

```
Result r = products.stream()
                    .collect(teeingList(
                            List.of(
                                    (Collector<Product, Object, Double>) Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getUnits),
                                    (Collector<Product, Object, Double>) Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getMktVal),
                                    (Collector<Product, Object, Double>) Collectors.summingDouble(Product::getMktVal),
                                    (Collector<Product, Object, Double>) Collectors.summingDouble(Product::getUnits)
                            ),
                            (List<Double> results) -> new Result(astcls, results.get(0), results.get(1), results.get(2), results.get(3))
                    ));
```

For some weird reason I couldn't get rid of the type casts even though IntelliJ tells me they are unnecessary...

Another last downside of this is that you have to either use all the same types (like double) or need to work on Object and cast the results you get to the appropriate type. The Result-Class of course has now even more fields:

```
class Result {
    private String astcls;
    private double avgUnits;
    private double avgMktVal;
    private double sumUnits;
    private double sumMktVal;
}
```

To address the confusion of OP in the comments, this is how the full main-Method should look afterwards:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Product> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(new Product("abc", 123, 4455));
    list1.add(new Product("bbc", 5454, 4467755));
    list1.add(new Product("abc", 66, 446555));
    list1.add(new Product("cc", 12773, 4455));
    list1.add(new Product("abc", 13323, 445875));
    list1.add(new Product("abddc", 12335, 445755));

    Map<String, List<Product>> result = list1.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getAstcls));

    result.forEach((astcls, products) -> {
        Result r = products.stream()
                .collect(teeingList(
                        List.of(
                                (Collector<Product, Object, Double>) Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getUnits),
                                (Collector<Product, Object, Double>) Collectors.averagingDouble(Product::getMktVal),
                                (Collector<Product, Object, Double>) Collectors.summingDouble(Product::getMktVal),
                                (Collector<Product, Object, Double>) Collectors.summingDouble(Product::getUnits)
                        ),
                        (List<Double> results) -> new Result(astcls, results.get(0), results.get(1), results.get(2), results.get(3))
                ));


        System.out.println("astcls: " + astcls);
        System.out.println("Average Units: " + r.getAvgUnits());
        System.out.println("Average MktVal: " + r.getAvgMktVal());
        System.out.println("Sum Units: " + r.getSumUnits());
        System.out.println("Sum MktVal: " + r.getSumMktVal());
        System.out.println("-----");
    });
}



        System.out.println("astcls: " + astcls);
        System.out.println("Average Units: " + r.getAvgUnits());
        System.out.println("Average MktVal: " + r.getAvgMktVal());
        System.out.println("-----");
    });
}
```

The execution prints:

```
astcls: cc
Average Units: 12773.0
Average MktVal: 4455.0
Sum Units: 4455.0
Sum MktVal: 12773.0
-----
astcls: bbc
Average Units: 5454.0
Average MktVal: 4467755.0
Sum Units: 4467755.0
Sum MktVal: 5454.0
-----
astcls: abc
Average Units: 4504.0
Average MktVal: 298961.6666666667
Sum Units: 896885.0
Sum MktVal: 13512.0
-----
astcls: abddc
Average Units: 12335.0
Average MktVal: 445755.0
Sum Units: 445755.0
Sum MktVal: 12335.0
-----
```

Comment: I want to group with ASTCL and after that calculate the average accordingly.

Comment: @JaydeepChauhan yes I know, I just replaced the part inside the result.forEach(...) the rest (so the grouping) happens before that as in your question.

Comment: The `Result` class could also be a `record`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman the `Collectors.teeing` method was introduced in JDK 12, and records were introduced in JDK 16.

Comment: I added a custom teeing operator that is better to use, and should be java8

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want multiple streams, you could reduce both fields using atomic references, but the code looks a bit messier.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import lombok.Value;

public class Averaging {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Product> list1 = List.of(
                new Product("abc", 123, 4455),
                new Product("bbc", 5454, 4467755),
                new Product("abc", 66, 446555),
                new Product("cc", 12773, 4455),
                new Product("abc", 13323, 445875),
                new Product("abddc", 12335, 445755)
        );

        Map<String, List<Product>> result = list1.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getAstcls));

        result.forEach((astcls, products) -> {
            Product average = averageProducts(products);

            System.out.printf("astcls: %s%n", astcls);
            System.out.printf("Average Units: %f%n", average.getUnits());
            System.out.printf("Average MktVal: %f%n", average.getMktVal());
            System.out.printf("-----%n");
        });
    }

    private static Product averageProducts(List<Product> products) {
        AtomicReference<Double> units = new AtomicReference<>(0d);
        AtomicReference<Double> mktVal = new AtomicReference<>(0d);

        // Sum up all the values
        products.forEach(product -> {
            units.updateAndGet(v -> v + product.getUnits());
            mktVal.updateAndGet(v -> v + product.getMktVal());
        });

        // Divide by the size
        units.updateAndGet(v -> v / products.size());
        mktVal.updateAndGet(v -> v / products.size());

        return new Product(products.get(0).getAstcls(), units.get(), mktVal.get());
    }

    @Value
    static class Product {
        String astcls;
        double units, mktVal;
    }
}
```

**Note:** The way you originally had it is generally preferred, because you do not have to juggle around multiple atomic references. Each `Collectors.averagingDouble` call operates on one field.

Alternatively, you could write your own function that takes a variable number of accessors:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import lombok.Value;

public class Averaging {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Product> list1 = List.of(
                new Product("abc", 123, 4455),
                new Product("bbc", 5454, 4467755),
                new Product("abc", 66, 446555),
                new Product("cc", 12773, 4455),
                new Product("abc", 13323, 445875),
                new Product("abddc", 12335, 445755)
        );

        Map<String, List<Product>> result = list1.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getAstcls));

        result.forEach((astcls, products) -> {
            List<Double> averages = averageMultipleFields(products, Product::getUnits, Product::getMktVal);
            Product average = new Product(astcls, averages.get(0), averages.get(1));

            System.out.printf("astcls: %s%n", astcls);
            System.out.printf("Average Units: %f%n", average.getUnits());
            System.out.printf("Average MktVal: %f%n", average.getMktVal());
            System.out.printf("-----%n");
        });
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> List<Double> averageMultipleFields(List<T> items, Function<T, Double>... accessors) {
        // Totals
        List<AtomicReference<Double>> refs = Arrays.stream(accessors)
                .map((f) -> new AtomicReference<>(0d))
                .toList();
        // Sum up all the values
        items.forEach(item -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < accessors.length; i++) {
                Function<T, Double> accessor = accessors[i];
                refs.get(i).updateAndGet(v -> v + accessor.apply(item));
            }
        });
        // Divide by the size
        for (int i = 0; i < accessors.length; i++) {
            refs.get(i).updateAndGet(v -> v / items.size());
        }
        return refs.stream().map(AtomicReference::get).toList();
    }

    @Value
    static class Product {
        String astcls;
        double units, mktVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have numbers of field for average calculation.If somehow we can use Collectors.AveragingDouble() multiple times in single stream API then the code becomes easier. Is this possible?